# Added button reference in designer and it throws a null error in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button that was in my markup, but wasn't accessible in the codebehind, until I added to the designer of the page. Now when I run the page and check an ID to whether I want the button enabled or disabled, I get an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I have no idea why its throwing that.

This is the code that I put into the designer so I can access the button

```
/// <summary>
/// Added this so i can access this button in the code behind
/// </summary>
protected global::DevExpress.Web.ASPxButton xbtnDelete;

/// <summary>
/// Added this so i can access it in the codebehind
/// </summary>
protected global::DevExpress.Web.ASPxButton xbtnView;
```

This is the buttons in the markup

```
<dx:GridViewDataColumn VisibleIndex="0" Caption="" FieldName="Delete" Width="100" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="xbtnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="xbtnDelete_Click"
            CommandArgument='<%# Container.VisibleIndex%>' Theme="Office2010Silver">
            <Image IconID="edit_delete_16x16" ToolTip="Edit"></Image>
            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {e.processOnServer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');}" />
        </dx:ASPxButton>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataColumn VisibleIndex="0" Caption="" FieldName="View" Width="100" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxButton ID="xbtnView" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="xbtnView_Click"
            CommandArgument='<%# Container.VisibleIndex%>' Theme="Office2010Silver">
            <Image IconID="miscellaneous_viewonweb_16x16" ToolTip="Edit"></Image>
        </dx:ASPxButton>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```

This is the code where I'm catching the error

```
private void CheckRoleLevel(int roleid)
    {
        if (RoutingControler.CheckMyRolesAreHigherOrEqualThanComparedRole(Convert.ToInt32(roleid)).Equals(true))
        {
            xbtnDelete.Enabled = true;
            xbtnView.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            xbtnDelete.Enabled = false;
            xbtnView.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out where I was going wrong..I had to add the code in the HTMLCreated event for the grid. This allowed me to catch the buttons.